# Macro to autorun when opening workbook for specific usernames only

Tags: excel, vba

On a network at work there are several users. I need a spreadsheet to automatically run some code when **specific** users opens the workbook. When all other users open the workbook no macro will run. The users names are Alan Smith & Susan Wells.

Code is:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Sheets("ABG").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Hardcode").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Do you know how I can alter this to check if the user is Alan Smith or Susan Wells when the document is opening, and if it is Alan or Susan then run the code? But if it is Paul then just open the document without the macro running?

Thanks!

Comment: See [How do I get the current user name in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6255535/4088852).

Comment: use if Environ("Username") = "Paul" / or varible. then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current user name in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255535/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-name-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code (before create a copy backup)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim name As String

name = Application.InputBox("insert your name")

If (UCase(name) <> UCase("Alan Smith")) Then ' control input in UPPPERCASE MODE
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  ' active sheet1 if input is Alan Smith

    If UCase(name) <> UCase("Susan Wells") Then 'control input in UPPERCASE MODE

        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False ' if input no Alan Snit and Susan Wells close workbook
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate ' if input is Susan Wells active sheet2
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

You have to put this code in your thisworkbook file. You see the image.
I hope this help you

[image]