# How to remove all other users access from Shared workbook by using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have shared workbook (Office 2016 ) ,
when I need to remove all other users from user access list
, I did manually and it takes long time.
Now, I found the below code to do that, but the problem in code is trying to remove me from this list
and this in not allowed and I got the error found in below photo.

```
Sub Remove_All_Users()

    Dim UsrList()

    UsrList = ThisWorkbook.UserStatus

    For i = 1 To UBound(UsrList)

        ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i)

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current user name in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255535/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-name-in-vba), and skip that user in the loop.

Comment: No it doesn't answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide more details about why the earlier comment does not answer this question.

Comment: Is the issue due to the fact you need to remove *all* users, *including yourself*?

Comment: @Luuk , your provided answer give only current username and not remove other users from shared workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luuk suggested, get your username with `Application.UserName` (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.username)) or `Environ ("UserName")` and skip that user in the loop.

As described in MS documentation, [Workbook.UserStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus) property returns a 2D array containing:

- 1st element : user's name as a `String`
- 2nd element: last date of modification

This allows to test each User based on its name and delete it only if it's not you:

```
Sub Remove_All_Users()
    Dim UsrList()

    UsrList = ThisWorkbook.UserStatus

    For i = 1 To UBound(UsrList,1)
        If Not(UsrList(i,1) = Application.UserName) Then ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If my userName is "Waleed" , how to skip from the loop?

Comment: Add a condition for deleting user from UsrList: ```If Not(UsrList(i) = Application.UserName) Then ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i)```

Comment: @ Vincent ,this is not logic question , if you have answer it will be good from you , otherwise let other people try to help me .

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Try replacing this line ```ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i)``` in your code with the one I gave in my previous comment. It will delete users only if the user name isn't yours.

Comment: I tried and got this error "Subscript out of range" on this line:  If Not(UsrList(i) = Application.UserName) Then

Comment: From what I can see, `UsrList` is populated as a 2D Array.  As the name is the first element, try changing it to `ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i, 1)`.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I was about to write this. It's explained in MS documentation about ```Workbook.UserStatus``` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus

Comment: @Waleed_wwm I edited my answer to include last comments.

Comment: Now works perfectly , Many thanks "Vincent" and everyone helped on this question.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Don't take what I'm about to say in the wrong way, as I am trying to give you an advice. You come here with an issue about a shared workbook and some code. Primary purpose of StackOverflow is to help people when they have something they don't understand with conding, but it is NOT a way to get a piece of code perfectly written by others to solve your problem. We're here to give advices, and indicate things that may solve your issue, but NOT to write a complete code for you. If you're not familiar with coding, you should say it because it can change how people answer your questions.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Based on your question and comments, either you're not familiar with coding, or you haven't look for a solution by yourself. At first I didn't know how to solve your issue, since I never wrote any code about user rights for shared workbook. But by just doing some google searches, looking for ```Workbook.UserStatus``` documentation, and trying to understand where the issue came from, the solution was in the end not very difficult to figure out. So if you ever face an issue, try to understand 'what does what', read documentation, and you should be able to solve most of your problems.

Comment: @Vincent. Right , I am not familiar with complex coding. I searched throughly until I found that code in my question. Anyway , many thanks  for your patience and helpful answer.

Comment: I know this is an older thread but felt I needed to point out an error. In the line `If Not(UsrList(i,1) = Application.UserName) Then ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser (i)` the RemoveUser(i) eventually causes an error as i increments and the list gets shorter, causing i to go out of bounds. This is fixed by changing RemoveUser(i) to RemoveUser(1) as this will always remove the first user in the list regardless of list size.